# show that the Taylor series of $f (x) = e ^{-1 / x ^ 2}$ around $x_0 = 0$ is identically zero

Tags: real-analysis

Well, samebody knows how can I proof it $f(x) = e^{-1/x^2}$ around $x_0 = 0$ is identically zero??

Comment: 1) Differentiate 2) Evaluate 3) Rinse and repeat

Comment: Do you meant to ask that, despite the fact that there are no Taylor's series for the function there, if we just try and apply the usual formula, then the resulting Taylor's series will be identically 0?

Comment: @Gina, the taylor series certainly doesn't converge to the function, but that is different from saying it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

We claim that $f^{(n)}(x)=q_n(x)e^{-1/x^2}$ for some rational function $q_n$. Indeed, the case $n=0$ is clear. Now we induct; suppose the result holds for $n$. Then for $x>0$, we compute
$$
f^{(n+1)}(x)=\left(q_n'(x)-\frac{2q_n(x)}{x^3}\right)e^{-1/x^2}.
$$
Since $q_n$ is a rational function, so is the expression in parentheses. Thus the claim follows by induction.

Now we may write
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{p_n(x)}{r_n(x)e^{1/x^2}}$$
for some polynomials $p_n,r_n$. Letting $x\to 0$, we observe that the denominator blows up to $\infty$ faster than any polynomial. Thus $f_n(0)=0$.

Hence we have shown that all coefficients in the Taylor expansion around 0 must vanish.

**Edit:**
As Ted Shifrin points out, the evaluation of $f^{(n)}(0)$ was not entirely rigorous. To be more precise, we should compute $f^{(n)}(0)$ using the limit definition and the form of $f^{(n-1)}(x)$ for $x>0$.

Comment: You have to use the definition of the derivative(s) at $0$. You can't just assume $f^{(n)}(0)=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f^{(n)}(x)$.

Comment: I think it is pretty clear that the singularity is removable. After all we are talking about the Taylor series of $\exp(-1/x^2)$ about the point $x=0$, which is the only point at which the function doesn't even exist if we take it too literally. Is there something more subtle that I am missing here?